Custom messages of same name not bridged with ros1_bridge
I have created a custom message CustomMessage.m with the fields:
int32 id
geometry_msgs/Pose pose
geometry_msgs/Twist[] twists

In my ROS2 Humble workspace, this is stored as such:
─ ros2humble_ws
  └─ src
     └─ project
        └─ interface_package
           └─ msg
              └─ CustomMessage.m

I then run a Docker container with ROS1 Noetic and ROS2 Galactic.
My ROS1 Noetic workspace in my Docker container is:
─ ros1noetic_ws
  └─ src
     └─ project
        └─ interface_package
           └─ msg
              └─ CustomMessage.m

and the bridge workspace is:
─ bridge_ws
  └─ src
     └─ ros1_bridge

To build everything, I first build my ros2humble_ws:
colcon build
source install/setup.bash

In my Dockerfile, I build like this:
RUN mkdir -p ~/ros1noetic_ws/src && cd ~/ros1noetic_ws/src && \
    mkdir project && cd project && \
    git clone https://github.com/user/interface_package.git && \
    cd ~/ros1noetic_ws && \
    . /opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh && \
    catkin_make --install

#Clone bridge source code and build
RUN mkdir -p ~/bridge_ws/src && \
    cd ~/bridge_ws/src && \
    git clone -b galactic https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge.git && \
    cd .. && \
    . /opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh && \
    . /opt/ros/galactic/setup.sh && \
    . ~/ros1noetic_ws/devel/setup.sh && \
    colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-force-configure


# Set the ROS middleware environment variable
ENV RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp

# And add the scripts and everything needed for the entrypoint
RUN mkdir shell_scripts
COPY shell_scripts /shell_scripts
RUN chmod +x /shell_scripts/entrypoint.sh && \ 
    chmod +x /shell_scripts/start_robot.sh && \
    chmod +x /shell_scripts/start_bridge.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/shell_scripts/entrypoint.sh" ]

start_bridge.sh does:
#!/bin/bash
set -e

source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash
ros2 daemon stop
ros2 daemon start
cd ~/bridge_ws
source install/setup.bash

ros2 run ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge --print-pairs
ros2 run ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge --bridge-all-topics

exec "$@"

Everything builds, but my message is not shown when I do --print-pairs. I even added a mapping.yaml file in my ROS2 Humble workspace (even though the packages have the same name), but I do not see my CustomMessage.
